# What is the difference between Bundle Identifier and Product Bundle Identifier?

Tags: ios

I want to know the difference between the `bundle Identifier` (in `info.plist`).
And the Product `Bundle Identifier` (in the `Build Setting -> Packaging -> Product Bundle Identifier`).

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BUNDLE IDENTIFIER is the namespace of your app, must be unique in the App Store world

PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER is a variable in your project.pbxproj file. Apple says from the Xcode 7 release notes that PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER is now "the recommended place to set the Bundle Identifier for a target." So if you're using BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER anyplace else in your project, you have to change it to PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER to keep things in sync.

Answer (score 2):

**Bundle Identifier -**

This is unique identifier for your application. Operating System uses this to uniquely identify your app. On App Store, every app has this as unique.

> CFBundleIdentifier (String - iOS, OS X) uniquely identifies the
>   bundle. Each distinct app or bundle on the system must have a unique
>   bundle ID. The system uses this string to identify your app in many
>   ways. For example, the preferences system uses this string to identify
>   the app for which a given preference applies; Launch Services uses the
>   bundle identifier to locate an app capable of opening a particular
>   file, using the first app it finds with the given identifier; in iOS,
>   the bundle identifier is used in validating the app’s signature.
>
> The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that
>   contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.)
>   characters. The string should also be in reverse-DNS format. For
>   example, if your company’s domain is Ajax.com and you create an app
>   named Hello, you could assign the string com.Ajax.Hello as your app’s
>   bundle identifier.

**Product Bundle Identifier -**

This is a variable in Xcode Project File, form XCode 7.0 Apple recommends to set Product Bundle Identifier and then user $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) in CFBundleIdentifier in Info.plist

> The new build setting Product Bundle Identifier
>   (PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) is the recommended place to set the Bundle
>   Identifier for a target. The target’s Info.plist should be configured
>   to use this build setting by referencing it as
>   $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) in the value for the CFBundleIdentifier
>   key.